# Missing hypothesis in the equivalence between functionally structured spaces and smooth $n$-manifolds

Tags: smooth-manifolds

In [Problem 1](https://books.google.com/books?id=wuUlBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA71) [Bredon, Topology and Geometry, Chapter II] it reads that a functional structure $F$ on a second countable Hausdorff space defines an $n$-manifold if, and only if, there is a cover with open sets $U$ and functions $f_1,\dots,f_n\in F(U)$ such that
$$
  g\in F(U)\iff \textrm{there exists $h$ smooth with }g = h\circ(f_1,\dots,f_n).
$$
To me the case where $F(U)$ is the set of constant functions is a counterexample for the *if* part.

Am I missing anything? If not, which additional hypothesis should we add?

---

A  **functionally structured space** is a topological space $(X,{\cal T})$ along with an assignment $U\mapsto F(U)$ for $U\in\cal T$, where $F(U)$ is subalgebra of $C(X,\mathbb R)$ that satisfies

1. $F(U)$ includes all constant functions;
2. $V\subseteq U$ and $f\in F(U)\implies f|_V\in F(V)$, and
3. $f\colon U\to\mathbb R$, $f|_{U_i}\in F(U_i)$ for all $i\in I$ and $U=\bigcup_{i\in I} U_i \implies f\in F(U)$.

Comment: What is a functional structure?

Comment: @FedericoFallucca I've added the definition.

Comment: A functional structure is not a space, as defined, so how can it be a manifold?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews My bad. I've rewritten the problem.

Comment: It does look like there is something missing. Perhaps that $h$ must be unique? That would mean that the each $f_i$ would have to have all of $\mathbb R$ as the range. (Or perhaps just a dense subset of $\mathbb R?$)

Comment: Strictly speaking, the constant functions don't satisfy item 3 in the definition of functionally structured space. If $U$ is the union of two disjoint open subsets and $f$ is constant on each of those subsets but with different values, then 3 is violated. But locally constant functions work, so you're right that more hypotheses are needed.

Comment: Please, use descriptive titles. "Missing hypothesis?" tells nothing about the subject of the question.

Comment: @jjagmath Thanks for the indication.